# How to Populate the list of custom post type categories

Tags: php, functions, categories

Default categories are populated like this →

```
<?php
                if( $terms = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=name' ) ) : // to make it simple I use default categories
                    echo '<select name="categoryfilter"><option value="all">All</option>';
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                        echo '<option value="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</option>'; // ID of the category as the value of an option
                    endforeach;
                    echo '</select>';
                endif;
            ?>
```

[image]

I tried to put `vcategory` instead of `category`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide more details, it is not clear what you are trying to achive. Do you want to show all custom post type categories?

Comment: Yes, thats right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second param fort historia function is deprecated, so it would be much nicer to pass params as an array:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'vcategory',
    'hide_empty' => false,

) );
```

But if you want to show a select filled with terms of given taxonomy, there’s a function for that:

```
wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'show_option_all'    => 'All',
    'orderby'            => 'name',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'         => 1, // change to 0 if empty terms should be shown to
    'echo'               => 1,
    'selected'           => 0,
    'name'               => 'categoryfilter',
    'taxonomy'           => 'vcategory',
    'value_field'        => 'slug',
) );
```